# Weird image whitespace

Tags: css, html, ce-1.9.3.0

[image]

All images get these white borders around them all over the page. Even in product view and category view. I havent found any CSS that would do that and would'nt belive it is some kind of plugin.
Is anyone experienced that before?

Magento 1.9.3

**To clarify: these white areas appear even when I insert image as big as the container**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not css issue. When you resize the image the magento will automatically add the white background to fill the container size.
use `keepFrame(false)`

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize);
```

here are  [example1](http://inchoo.net/magento/properly-remove-white-image-frame-upon-resizing-photos-in-magento/)  [example2](http://www.measureddesigns.com/removing-the-white-background-from-magento-thumbnails/) how to remove white background

Comment: I have both media.phtml files that my theme is using and neither has "keepFrame" in them. The way these images are called is: <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
or

Comment: @raulicious use `keepFrame(false)` will remove white background

Comment: I added keepFrame(false) before every resize() callout in media.phtml, but the white borders did'nt go away. Should I also remove resize maybe?

Comment: @raulicious try with different size then if it worked then remove and clear cache before maybe cache is reason or delete var/cache folder too

Comment: It worked now, template path hints was giving me wrong template information to look at, that is why it did'nt work at first. Thanks!